# Determine command status in C shell

Tags: shell, tcsh

I wrote my c shell script which need to determine the command status. In the below program
`line 4` command was not successful. But I got status still `0`. I do not understand why.
As per my understanding, I should get `1`. Am I right? `Line No 3` command was successful.
I know it is very basic question but it is not homework. We need to determine the job status
So I have tried with simple script

`Line 4` give me error that it is unable to load this version tool

```
1 #!/bin/csh -f
2         source /global/etc/csh.cshrc
3         module unload her
4         module load her/2012
5         echo $status
6         if ( $status != 0) then
7          echo "Error: abhishek Unable to execute  module load her/2012"
8          exit
9         endif
```

Comment: I  understand if you do not than you should not try.But in Existing code it is implemented and my client want only solution to fix this script

Comment: @WilliamPursell: Good advice, but irrelevant; the same problem would have happened with bash.

Comment: The original version of your script had `echo $status` before the `if` statement; that was the cause of your problem. By "fixing" the code in your question, you've made the question useless to future readers. Please don't do that. Show the problem in the question; accept an answer to indicate the solution. I've rolled your question back to a version that shows the problem.

Comment: @KeithThompson,I understand and I should not change main question.But I was also trying to debug issue and put echo $status into code.But In the original script I do not have and was facing issue.So I have update question to  avoid multiple posting  with minor modification. But Anyway I should also be careful before posting question.As people are giving me sometime for resolve this issue.They should not feel guilty why have they  given me time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is you are testing the status after the echo command. The echo command was successful, so it reset the status to 0.
Here is some sample code to show the issue

```
#!/bin/csh -f

sh -c "exit 2"
echo status is $status or $?
echo status is $status or $?
```

which outputs

```
status is 2 or 2
status is 0 or 0
```

Another thing you can do is use #!/bin/csh -fe which causes the script to exit as soon as the error occurs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply.I was checking the status so I have added into code.But Status is not present into main file

Comment: If you want to examine the status more than once, save it in a variable: `set saved_status = $status ; echo "status = $saved_status" ; if ( $status != 0 ) ...`

Answer (score 1):

Not quite right.
Having saved the status of the module load command
then it is that saved status which you consult!

set saved_status = $status ; echo "status = $saved_status" ; if ( $saved_status != 0 ) ...